# beamer: headers are cut with CambridgeUS and beamerthemeshadow

Tags: beamer

I am creating a presentation with beamer and the theme CambridgeUS. My problem is that the section and subsection titles displayed in the header are slightly cut as soon as `\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}` is used. It affects only characters which extend below the baseline, e.g. p, q and y. Here is a small example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{document}

 \section{section with p and q}
 \subsection{subsection with y}
 \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{first frame}
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

**Edit by John Wickerson.** I intended to add a picture to demonstrate the problem, but when I compiled the code, I couldn't see anything wrong. Does it look like this on your machine?

[image]

@John Wickerson: On my machine it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: Your example looks good in my computer. May be you use an old beamer version.

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with `beamer` and these cases, but it was (or at least should have been) fixed some time ago. As such, the best answer here is to update your `beamer` to the latest release version.

If that doesn't work, please edit in the `File list` you get in the `.log` file after adding `\listfiles` to your input.